# SSRS show/hide parameter pane by clicking a button

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have created a report which contains a number of parameters so that the user can filter the data.

By default the show/hide paramters tab is closed.
To access these parameters the user needs to click on the usual button to expand the header area and view all the possible parameters.

This is all fine, I want the parameters to be hidden by default as it take up a large proportion of the report and not everyone wants to see them.

What I do want however is to create a text box called 'Use filtering' or something similar and create an 'action' so that when this box is clicked on the URL for the report with some sort of additional command on the end included so that it reloads the current page but with the command to show the parameter pane.

I have tried adding the following to the URL of the report page but it does not work:

```
&rc:HeaderArea=full&rc:Parameters=true
```

and also

```
&rv:HeaderArea=full&rc:Parameters=true
```

All it does it reload the page but with no changes to the parameter pane.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here.

Comment: You can only pass these paramaters to the RS WebService not the RS Web Server. Make sure your loading the report via `http://abc/ReportServer` and not via `http://abc/Reports`

Comment: @general exception Its loading the report via /Reports

Comment: load via `http://abc/ReportServer` and not `http://abc/Reports`. The latter does not support them paramaters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use these parameters, you must load the report via the Web Service URL rather than the front end URL.

Typically on a standard install these are `http://MyServer/Reports` (Front end) and `http://ReportServer` (WebService). Only the WebService URL will accept the parameters you are trying to use, the other will just ignore them, hence why the report is loading but not observing the parameters your passing to it.